# How to compile Graal Native Image on MacOs BigSur?

Tags: gradle, micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

When I try to compile with `./gradlew nativeCompile`

```
java -version
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.3.0 (build 17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08, mixed mode, sharing)

native-image --version
GraalVM 22.3.0 Java 17 CE (Java Version 17.0.5+8-jvmci-22.3-b08)
```

```
Error: Error compiling query code (in /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-4935784945826410470/PosixDirectives.c). Compiler command '/usr/bin/cc -Wall -Werror -Wno-tautological-compare -ObjC -o /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-4935784945826410470/PosixDirectives /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-4935784945826410470/PosixDirectives.c' output included error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:91:143: error: function does not return NSString
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
```

The stack-trace isn't any more useful, the error has something to do about a function not returning NSString.

```
Error: Error compiling query code (in /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-17577305799927673130/PosixDirectives.c). Compiler command '/usr/bin/cc -Wall -Werror -Wno-tautological-compare -ObjC -o /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-17577305799927673130/PosixDirectives /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-17577305799927673130/PosixDirectives.c' output included error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:91:143: error: function does not return NSString
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Error compiling query code (in /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-17577305799927673130/PosixDirectives.c). Compiler command '/usr/bin/cc -Wall -Werror -Wno-tautological-compare -ObjC -o /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-17577305799927673130/PosixDirectives /var/folders/zr/ctjr8g2574ggz5xjzrd6jyxw0000gn/T/SVM-17577305799927673130/PosixDirectives.c' output included error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSBundle.h:91:143: error: function does not return NSString
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:139)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.c.NativeLibraries.reportErrors(NativeLibraries.java:371)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.processNativeLibraryImports(NativeImageGenerator.java:1715)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeLibraries(NativeImageGenerator.java:1121)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:915)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:575)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.run(NativeImageGenerator.java:535)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:403)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:580)
    at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:128)
```

Comment: Is this error happens only on MacOS?

Comment: I guess, I don't have another platform to test on...